# XSD Element validation for empty or NA value

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using:

```
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
```

The XSD Should validate element **Name** to be either **empty** or **NA** value.

Another other values apart from being **empty** value or **NA** value should not 
be accepted.

Comment: Rollback reason:  I've already correctly answered your original question.  Replacing it so dramatically undermines the provided answer, which you merely are having trouble implementing.  Happy to help with that too:  Just drop `type="xsd:string"` that you forgot to remove when you merged in my answer and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Huges: i have network issue and my browser reacts in a peculiar way while doing my posts. I'm sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: @Huges How do i test the below element validation while using the xsd as SOAP response XML. Please advise

Comment: It will work in any cotext.  If you're having trouble, post a minimal, complete example (MCE) that shows the issue in a separate question.  Can't advise further without seeing an MCE.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict `xs:string` to be one of two enumerated values: `""` (empty string) or `"NA"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Name">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value=""/>
        <xs:enumeration value="NA"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @kjhuges if i apply your changes i get the error message as "Element 'NAME' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element." Please check above.

Comment: You forgot to take `type="xsd:string"` off of the element definition; it's not needed (indeed, not allowed) when defining the content model locally.